# Why is the run time for these nested loops O(n)

Tags: data-structures, big-o

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i=i*2)
    for(j=1; j<=n; j=j+i) 
      x++;
```

Why is the run time for this O(n)? Shouldn't it be O(log n)*O(n) = O(nlog n)? Since we have O(log n) for first loop, and O(n) for the second one?

Sorry, I am new at Big O analysis.

Comment: The inner loop doesn't make `n` iterations; it makes `n/lg(n)` iterations because it increments by `i` every time.

Comment: I would say that the OP is correct: O(nlog n) because the outer loop does log(n) loops and the inner, well just in the first outer loop iteration (i=1) does loops n times (n/2 for i=2, n/4 for i=4)...

Comment: Big-oh notation is not tight; it may be technically correct to say that the loop runs in O(n lg n) time, but the argument for saying so is weak and does not *preclude* a tighter bound such as O(n) (which is also correct).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is in fact `O(n)`. Observe that the inner loop is *dependent* on the outer loop (because we have `j = j + i`), and each turn of the inner loop **does not** contribute the same amount of running time, so it is inappropriate to merely multiply the complexity of the outer loop by the complexity of the inner loop in order to get the total running time!

In fact, for a given `i`, since we increase `j` by `i` each turn, the inner loop takes values `1, 1 + i, 1 + 2i, ...`, so there are in total around `n / i` possible values.

Since the outer loop only takes value that are power of `2` (i.e. `1, 2, 4, ...`), we have the following:

```
i                No. of values the inner loop takes = n / i
------------------------------------------------------------
1                      n / 1 = n / (2^0)
2                      n / 2 = n / (2^1)
4                      n / 4 = n / (2^2)
.                            .
.                            . 
.                            .
2^⌊log(n)⌋               n / (2^⌊log(n)⌋)
```

Therefore the complexity is given by:

```
  n / (2^0) + n / (2^1) + n / (2^⌊log(n)⌋)
= n * ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/2^2 + ... + 1/2^⌊log(n)⌋)
= n * (2 - 1 / 2^(⌊log(n)⌋+1))
< 2n
= O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed like this using Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is O(nlogn).
Explanation - as in the 1st loop you are jumping on every 2nd element and for this every element you are running n times. Hence O(nlogn)